# VSCode resets theme when switching tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-editor

Occurs when simply switching, or opening / closing a tab, and does not revert if "undoing" the tab change. Below gif's on a freshly reinstalled VSCode, though I didn't erase all cache, preferences, etc. when uninstalling.

What is the problem, and how to fix?

---

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this without any extensions, and with a clean `settings.json`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know, but you gave me an idea which led to a resolution - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File -> Preferences -> Color Theme` apparently doesn't change global settings, nor do I know what exactly it changes - but I circumvented the problem by changing the `"workbench.colorTheme"` and `"theme-by-language.themes"` values in `settings.json` to the same color theme name.

I found `settings.json` via `File -> Preferences -> Extensions -> JSON -> Edit in settings.json`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this was due to a rogue VSCode extension not behaving properly - disabling the [BioSyntax extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reageyao.biosyntax) fixed it.

If you're running into this issue but don't have that specific extension installed, it might be worth disabling all your extensions and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I had the same issue, and it was also BioSyntax, which I've totally forgotten about. Thanks for this answer, I'd have never found it myself. If anyone has time (I don't unfortunately), it would be nice to file a bug report for the extension.

Comment: I didn't think this would solve my issue, but for some reason i had this exact extension installed and removing it fixed my issues as well (no idea when I ever needed it personally, maybe some dependency?). Also just saw, that they seem to have a section about fixing that issue on their extension page: Which is to set your theme in their settings. So it's intended behaviour??

Comment: Thank you for this. BioSyntax is the reason mine was broken too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, inverting screen colours would also switch VSCode colour theme back to **Light High Contrast**. I could alter these defaults by going to `Settings` (`⌘,` on mac) -> `Workbench` -> `Appearance` and changing the option under `Preferred High Contrast Light Colour Theme` to what I wanted.